# Trigonometry problem help

Tags: trigonometry

[Please see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOCDG.png)
[image]

**No solution please. I'd really like a hint, just a hint.**

So far, I've managed to just find the lengths of the triangle, in terms of cos theta. Need help with part A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Connect C to the vertex B of the right angled triangle ABD....now use the fact that angle in a semi circle is a right angle and a little bit of elementary trigonometry to get the first result...once u get the first part u just need to put in the values to get the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Connect $C$ to the center of the circle. Study the new triangle formed.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Since $\;AB\;$ is a diameter, $\;\angle CBA=90^\circ\;$ . Also, $\;\angle CBA=90-\theta\;$ and $\;\sin(90-\theta)=\cos\theta\;$ . Join $\;C\;$ with $\;B\;$ .

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about joining C with B. However, I'm not sure of the angles. Something in my mind is telling me that when two chords meet, they meet at right angles... Is this correct?

Comment: @user375494 No, of course not. Why would they? Observe the straight triangle $\;\Delta ABC\;$, and do trigonometry to calculate the length of AC. Now do the same with the straight $\;\Delta ABD\;$ to calculate $\;AD\;$ . Now substract lengths...

Comment: @user375494 You seem to be just enlightened by other answer, in spite the fact that this one already gave you clues for that...funny.

Answer (score 0):

- 1) Express angle $\angle ADB$ as a function of $\theta.$
- 2) Show that $AC=cos(\theta)$ and $AD=6 \sec(\theta).$
- 3) Conclude.